My list validation formula does not work on choice column
I have a SharePoint list with choice columns. I want to set a validation rule that says if Column A = "Yes" and Column B is set to "No" then it should error.
The idea is that when Column A is set to "Yes", Column B must also be set to "Yes".
This is the formula I have and when I apply to test it, SharePoint lets me add a new user to the list with Column A set to Yes and Column B set to No.
What am I doing wrong?
=IF([Column A]="Yes";IF([Column B]="No";FALSE;TRUE);TRUE)


Are these choice columns single selection or multiple selections are allowed for these choice columns?

Try using formula like this once: =IF([Column A]="Yes",IF([Column B]="No",FALSE,TRUE),TRUE). Let me know if it works for you.

The columns are set to have only two choices, Yes or No. I have to use semicolons, my Sharepoint won't accept commas in formulas..

Having two choices is fine - check your column settings once if any column allows multiple selections. Also, are you using correct display names of your columns? Your formula syntax looks good to me. Which language are you using for your SharePoint site?

I've checked the columns and I've turned off allow for multiple selections. Regarding the names, how can I find the correct display name? I'm using the columns available in the list next to where I enter the formula..

You can get column display name from column settings or list form or list view: https://i.sstatic.net/YFNnn9x7.png. Can you add a screenshot to your question showing where exactly you are adding the formula?

I go into List settings --> Validation settings:

I enter the formula here:
https://tinypic.host/image/2024-04-30-14-35-12.DrAN0c
